# JQuery FCKeditor how to install?

Tags: jquery

i want add FCKEditor into JSP
i found plugin for FCKEditor by Jquery
But i was do the same guide but not work
The plugin here:

```
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/FCKEditor/
```

the following guide:

```
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/FCKEditor/#tab-Usage
```

i choose method 3 but when i view the jsP it just text area isn't FCKEditor

i wonder with the config path

```
$.fck.config = {path: '/path/to/fck/directory/', height:300 };
```

thi fck in the path it mean fckeditor or fckeditor plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The path should contain the path to the directory where you place the FCKeditor files. Make sure you have the FCKeditor files downloaded and placed in the right directory

**EDIT**

Use [CKeditor](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/CKEditor/) by the way. FCKeditor is an out-dated version.

Comment: i was download FCK Editor and install with following guide
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter
but it not work on jsp ??
when i call .ckeditor() in Netbeans 6.9 , i cant find the method ckeditor()

Comment: i was solved my problem with nicEditor :D thank you for your help